# MikroTik CRS354-48P-4S+2Q+ with RouterOS 7.10 stable - Unable to fast track connections

Tags: networking, router, switch, mikrotik-routeros, mikrotik

I'm not seeing any increase in throughput after trying to fast track connections.
A confirmation that things aren't working as they should is shown in the linked image.

Rule #0 counters aren't incremented and anything that hits rule #1 also hits rule #3.

[A useful screenshot of WinBox that I can't show you inline since I don't have 10 reputation points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqgpT.png)

The device has only been slightly configured.
I entered static IP settings, pointed the device to use a local DNS and NTP server and nothing else of interest that I can think off.

Some additional info:

```
/ip/firewall/filter> print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid; D - dynamic 
 0  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=forward action=passthrough 

 1    chain=forward action=fasttrack-connection hw-offload=yes connection-state=established,related protocol=tcp 

 2    chain=forward action=fasttrack-connection hw-offload=no connection-state=established,related protocol=udp 

 3    chain=forward action=accept connection-state=established,related,untracked
```

```
/interface/bridge/settings> print
              use-ip-firewall: yes
     use-ip-firewall-for-vlan: no
    use-ip-firewall-for-pppoe: no
              allow-fast-path: yes
      bridge-fast-path-active: no
     bridge-fast-path-packets: 0
       bridge-fast-path-bytes: 0
  bridge-fast-forward-packets: 0
    bridge-fast-forward-bytes: 0
```

From what I can see all the conditions listed here are satisfied:
https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Fasttrack

Hardware acceleration is disabled on the port I'm using under "Bridge - Ports", otherwise traffic won't hit the firewall rules.

Fast forward is enabled on the bridge, disabling it doesn't make a difference.

L3 Hw offloading is disabled on the port I'm using under "Switch - Port", enabling it doesn't make a difference.

L3 Hw offloading is enabled under "Switch", disabling it doesn't make a difference.

Under "Switch - L3 Hw Settings" both "Fasttrack Hw" and "Supports Fasttrack Hw" are enabled.

Are there any additional details that I can provide?

EDIT: Thanks to @u1686_grawity for asking me to provide additional details.
I was originally talking about port 48 on the switch, a PC is connected to this port.
I'm checking speeds via a speedtest via internet.
Traffic goes through port 1, where a router that provides internet access is connected.
So now I set port 1 just like port 48 but nothing changes.
These are 1Gbps copper ports that are on the same (the only one present) bridge, like all the other 46 ports of this kind.

Comment: Are the packets actually supposed to be routed or bridged? You only mention one port being used, is it the input port or output? Where is the other port? (Or are you routing between two VLANs on a single port?)

Comment: @u1686_grawity thanks for asking these important details. I updated the question.

Comment: You say that both ports belong to the same bridge. If that's the case, the CRS isn't doing any L3 routing – are you sure the packets go through its IP firewall rules at all? Bridging of ports in the same subnet would be L2 offload, not L3.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes, hardware acceleration is disabled on both ports under "Bridge - Ports", otherwise traffic won't hit the firewall rules.